# Flickr in drupal?

Tags: drupal, flickr

I am trying to get flickr images to work in Drupal, any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FlickrGallery](http://drupal.org/project/flickrgallery) module which is available for Drupal 6 as well as Drupal 7 to get all your images from your account.

Answer (score 10):

[Flickr drupal module](http://drupal.org/project/flickr)

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to sync your Flickr photos to Drupal content, check out: http://drupal.org/project/flickrsync

Comment: Hi, thanks, I'm sure its useful for someone who comes across this question. I asked the question in 2009, so I don't even remember asking this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

FLickr has a help page for Drupal

Comment: Is there a  link to that page you could add to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the media_flickr module,
but media is well tested module and there are a bunch of other modules that acts as plugins to the media module so I highly recommend that

here is the flickr: http://drupal.org/project/media_flickr